# Connecting two Linodes together with Django

Tags: django, linode

I have my Django code sitting on one linode secured with SSH.  I have my database sitting in a different linode secured with a different ssh key.

What do I need to do to make them talk with each other?

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the mysql server on system #2 from system #1? At simplest, just put the IP of the mysql server in your Django database config... It doesn't have anything to do with ssh (but maybe ssl) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html